# Realtime imagery from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps, google-earth

Can we use Google Earth Engine to get realtime (not later than a week is also fine) satellite images?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/, it has all the details.